# Can a processor make up for performance drop caused by a hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, performance

I have a processor that is very strong and a hard drive that is very slow. I have installed a lot of heavy programs and IDEs on my system, on a laptop I had before if I had installed as many programs as I have done on this laptop then it would hang freeze and throw ARNs on every window I interact with. The processor of this laptop is a core i5-seventh generation and somehow, this system is very responsive despite the hard drive having very low read and write speeds(100MBs/s-100MB/s), I feel like this processor is making up for the slow hard drive with it's clock speed. Is this possible and can one hardware still boost system performance despite others in the system being weak, Thank you.

Comment: No. A bottleneck is a bottleneck. Buy an SSD if possible

Comment: If an app lives only in RAM & doesn't often read/write to the drive, the drive speed will make no difference. Otherwise, it will be very slow compared to an SSD.

Comment: @Tetsujin, well explained. So its got nothing to do with the hard drive? but wait, when i launch the programs, they load from hard drive

Comment: The startup time of programs is insane for this low speed hard drive, this processor is a system super booster

Comment: @Tetsujin not entirely true. The OS itself can be living on the same drive. Especially a failing drive could become really slow.

Comment: @LPChip - if there's enough RAM that there's no swap, then once everything is loaded it will make no difference. OP says 8GB in comments… which definitely isn't enough to account for this apparent speed, so let's assume there's a bottleneck, but one the OP is used to from previous HD-based machines.

Comment: @Tetsujin my point is more that the OS will also do stuff to the disk and to ram. an app will not live in ram if its closed. It may be cached, but there's usually still some disk access. Also some apps rely on files, that obviously won't live in RAM.

Comment: @LPChip - mine was simply that ***if*** everything's in RAM you won't see a difference. As we have since discovered the OP only has 8GB, barely enough to run an OS these days, then we'll have to assume this apparent speed is not real, but a misinterpreted comparison of the difference between the old & new machine.

Comment: @Tetsujin right... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

RAM can somewhat make up for a slow hard drive as it can be used as a buffer/cache (and is by default in most OS's including Windows) - and its the RAM most likely helping you here.

If waiting for disk IO consumes 98℅ of the time, no amount of clu procrssing power will make even 5℅ difference to the performance.  On the other hand, the the computer is doing the same kinds of things repeatedly and can memorise the data on the drive (ie in RAM)  it can greatly offset the slowness of the system.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for, it makes sense to assert that the RAM can save the system from a slow hard drive because the operating system will use it for primary buffer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A faster CPU helps, but is not the main hardware that help dealing with
a slow disk.

The main component that mitigates the slow disk is the RAM - more memory
allows Windows (or any OS) to keep a larger memory cache.

On the one hand, a larger cache increases the amount of data that is read
from disk and is kept in memory, so that a second reference to the same
data is resolved immediately.

On the other hand, it allows storing data that needs to be written to
the disk,
and lets the computer continue working, while the new data is
flushed to the disk at its speed.

In conclusion, probably your new computer has more memory than the old one,
which helps counter the slowness of the disk.

In the end, a faster disk would be the best improvement
for disk performance.

Comment: Your wrong, the memory size is the same both had 8 gigs of RAM.

Comment: It might be faster RAM, or perhaps a faster bus, that makes the memory cache more effective. The computer is a complex system where the performance is in function of the whole. Although upgrading a single component can help, there is a limit to how much is possible without upgrading more components.

Comment: @Mandela If you know the answer why are you adking the question.  Please enlighten us with your superior knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Any time the system accesses the drive will be slow no matter what processor you have.

System boot times, program loading, and saving files are all things that *might* see slight improvements on a faster processor during the periods when they are not waiting on the hard disk, i.e. when they are actually processing the data loaded. But the moment the hard disk is asked for data it will become a bottleneck.

Laptop hard disks are the worst culprit for this. They are slow, their seek times are awful and their peak bandwidth is generally bad at best.

Microsoft tried to mitigate this somewhat with their "fast startup" system which essentially uses the hibernation system to save the OS core upon shutting down. They tried to turn a mostly random disk seek startup sequence into a pretty much one big sequential read. It's an improvement, but in no way does it compete with a decent fast disk.

In my opinion the number one improvement any laptop can have is to replace an HDD with an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Although memory can eliviate diskwrites, it is still the OS that lives on that disk too.

In Windows, it is very easy to consume a lot of memory, in which case the memory is swapped to disk. A slow disk will still bottleneck and make things become slow.

In addition, traditional disks are slower because it has to seek data across the drive for every action it does, which include loading a program from disk to memory, performing logs by the OS itself, doing Windows Updates in the background and many more things that will write to disk.

Keep in mind that if a disk is quite a bit slower than it should be, it is likely that the disk is dying in which case it should be replaced to prevent dataloss. So if you suspect a problem with the disk, check the SMART info using Crystal Disk Info to ensure that the disk is still healthy.

A slow disk can also happen if it is nearly full and heavily fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

More memory can speed up things, but not the first time after boot.  So it would be responsive, but slow at boot and the first time you open each application.

Some operating systems support compression, which can reduce the amount of data that has to be read from disk at the expense of decompression time.  But this only increases bandwidth sometimes by a factor of 2-3 without helping latency much, and you'd have to trigger compression for files already on disk for it to help.

Comment: Your are also wrong, my system takes a maximum of 10 seconds to boot, which puts up a good fight when compared to the boot times systems with ssd record. My system opens applications quickly immediately I login which was not the case with my old laptop

Comment: No spinny rust hard drive is going to boot to an OS in 10 seconds. You are missing some information somewhere. Knowing the precise model of the computer may help.

Comment: Not wrong, just differently right depending on the hardware involved.  My point isn't if the machine is fast, my point is, can more memory make it faster?  And I've seen 25 year old HDs boot the OS in 10 seconds.  It just wasn't windoze.

Comment: @user10489, this guy #@Tetsujin likes to over generalize so much, how can you say there is no hard drive that can boot into the OS in less than 10 seconds?

Comment: Mandela - you haven't told us the OS, or the computer, so all we can do is generalise. You keep telling people they're wrong, but you never add any information to make our assumptions any different. No info, no more guesses. [btw, you don't need to tag the poster of an answer, they'll be notified anyway. You do need to tag anyone else if you want them to be notified. #@ stops the tag working.]